# Angular2 RC1 Service is losing initiated properties

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I'm working on an Angular2 app and this worked fine up until RC1 came out (though it was never tested in RC0).

Essentially I have a cacheService class that subscribes to Subjects on a 'remoteService' class.  Any components refer to the cacheService.players instead of making the request to the remoteService.  I do this because it also de-couples the application caching layer from the remoteService, allowing the cacheService to cache, and the remoteService to access the remote service.

However, when the component is instantiated, the cacheService constructor is called, which initializes the players[] array.

However, when the remoteService emits a player, the function inside the subscribe can't access the players[] array - it's uninitialized.

Again, this was working in Beta, but not in RC.

Am I missing something?

The caching service (simplified)

```
@Injectable()
export class cacheService {
   public players: any[];  

   constructor(private _service: remoteService) {
           this.players = [];

           _service.players.subscribe((p: player) => {
               if (this.players[p.id] && this.players[p.id].score)
                   p.score = this.players[p.id].score;

               this.players[p.id] = p;
           });
   }
}
```

The component (again simplified)

```
@Component({
    selector: 'player-view',
    templateUrl: '/Template/PlayerView'
})
export class PlayerView implements OnInit {
    public playerCache = any[];

    constructor(private _cacheService: cacheService) {
        this.playerCache = [];
    }

    getDraftData() {
            this._cacheService.getPlayers(league.id);
            this.playerCache = this._cacheService.players;
        }
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getDraftData();
    }
}
```

Edit: corrected transcription mistake.

Comment: Hard to tell from the code you posted. How does `getPlayers()` look like? What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: The error actually occurs when attempting to access a property of the this.players[] array (e.g., this.players[p.id].score).  The error message is "Cannot read property score of undefined".

Comment: The problem is obviously with your data.  Check if the data is actually set in `_service.players.subscribe(...)` before you access it. `Observable` is async. Just because you subscribed to it doesn't mean you immediately get a value. The value may be set eventually but it definitely doesn't immediately.

Comment: I actually found the issue (see answer) thanks to you're questions.   There was a line of code accessing the player array outside of the various checks.  It made it _look_ like the array was not initialized at all.

Answer (score 0):

This line is invalid

```
this.playerCache = this._dataService.players;
```

The service reference is `this._cacheService`. There is no `this._dataService`. `dataService` (still different - no `_`) is the type of `this._cacheService`

Comment: You're correct, that was actually a transcription error from when I was simplifying the code.  I've updated the snippet accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  I had a line that was accessing the property of the player array without being checked.

For example:

```
if (this.players[p.id]) 
    temp = this.players[p.id].score

this.players[p.id].score = temp
```

The problem arose when the players[p.id] was uninstantiated.